# CSS transition going backwards/reverse

Tags: css, animation, transition

I'm wondering if is there any way to use the same CSS transition instance to both move it forward and then backwards/reverse. For example, lets say I have this transition:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-transition {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And two runners for this transition. One does the fade in and the other does the fade out:

```
.fade-in {
    -webkit-animation: fade-transition .2s linear backwards;
}

.fade-out {
    -webkit-animation: fade-transition .2s linear forwards;
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to use the same transition to do both the fade in and the fade out but the way I'm doing it doesn't work.

[Here is the example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aduwif/5/).

Comment: just as example, here's an updated snippet: http://jsbin.com/aduwif/4

Comment: @GNi33 still not what I want. I want to use the same transition instance to make the fade in and the fade out. So when the user rolls over the thumbnail, it should fade out and when the user rolls out the thumbnail, it should fade in. I don't want a loop animation. [Here is the updated file on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aduwif/8/).

Comment: something more like this? http://jsbin.com/aduwif/11

Comment: @GNi33 Yes, the effect should look exactly like that but the thing is that I want to know if it's possible to do it by using a single CSS transition instance. The idea is to have two different classes which runs the same transition; but one should execute it backwards. On the example I gave, you run the transition forwards and it makes opacity goes from 0 to 1. However if you run it backwards you make opacity goes from 1 to 0, which is a fade out effect.

Answer (score 3):

Use `percentage` instead of `from` and `to`

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-transition {
    0%, 100% { opacity: 0; }
    50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

You can iterate this number of times you want or just set it to infinite

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the way to go. Though I need to control its iteration to get the result I want.  I might be over thinking this :)